# Drawing ellipses on matplotlib basemap projections-How to extend the basemap class

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am new to python and matplotlib (and stackoverflow). Can you please tell me how do I extend my basemap class with this ellipse function? The original post "Drawing ellipses on matplotlib basemap projections" from regeirk is exact what I need but I do not know how to extend the class.

Here is the code from regeirk:
[Drawing ellipses on matplotlib basemap projections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161144/drawing-ellipses-on-matplotlib-basemap-projections)

I do not know how to implement it extending the basemap class. I have never done this before.

I hope I provided all the info.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. You can just edit your original post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996165/re-drawing-ellipses-on-matplotlib-basemap-projections rather than creating a new one. In fact, you should do so and then delete this one, in order to avoid duplicates. The 'edit' button is right below the post (between 'share' and 'flag')

Comment: Thank you Spencer.  I just deleted the old one since this is the most complete post.

Answer (score 1):

With python, you can extend a class without needing to modify the Basemap sourcecode itself. Simply importing the following code (maybe by just having it inline in your script) will modify the functionality of a class (In this case, we may as well modify the Basemap class):

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

def ellipse(self, x0, y0, a, b, n, ax=None, **kwargs):
    print 'Hello world!'

Basemap.ellipse = ellipse
```

Now, when you create a Basemap instance it will have the appropriate "ellipse" method.

See also http://dietbuddha.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/python-metaprogramming-dynamically.html