# Rendering an ellipse using matplotlib to a basemap with a projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, ellipse

I'm plotting an ellipse using matplotlib using this code:

```
lat = float(ellipse['cy'])
lng = float(ellipse['cx'])
width = float(ellipse['rx']) / 111111.0
height = float(ellipse['ry']) / 111111.0
rot = float(ellipse['rotation'])  # + 180?
xpt, ypt = lng, lat
if m != None:
    xpt, ypt = m(lng, lat)
ell = Ellipse(xy=(xpt, ypt), width=width*2, height=height*2,
    angle=rot, edgecolor='black', facecolor='none')
ax.add_patch(ell)
ax.annotate(ellipse['label'], (xpt, ypt))
```

I'm using this code to create the basemap:

```
# setup Lambert Conformal basemap.
m = Basemap(width=12000000, height=9000000, projection='lcc',
            resolution='c', lat_1=45., lat_2=55, lat_0=50, lon_0=-107.)
# m.shadedrelief()
m.drawlsmask(land_color='coral', ocean_color='aqua', lakes=True)
```

The ellipse isn't rendered. If I don't use a basemap and set m to None, then the ellipse is rendered. Do I need to do anything specific for the ellipse when rendering to a projected map? I'm using matplotlib 3.6.2 on Python 3.11.0 (Windows 11).

I read [Drawing ellipses on matplotlib basemap projections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161144/drawing-ellipses-on-matplotlib-basemap-projections) but it's 11 years old, so I'm not sure if the code is still relevant.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could give [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) a try...

From the [docs](https://eomaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#annotations-markers-lines-logos-etc):

```
from eomaps import Maps
m = Maps(crs=4326)
m.add_feature.preset.coastline()

# ----- SINGLE MARKERS
# by default, MARKER DIMENSIONS are defined in units of the plot-crs!
m.add_marker(xy=(0, 0), radius=20, shape="rectangles",
             fc="y", ec="r", ls=":", lw=2)
m.add_marker(xy=(0, 0), radius=10, shape="ellipses",
             fc="darkorange", ec="r", ls=":", lw=2)

# MARKER DIMENSIONS can be specified in any CRS!
m.add_marker(xy=(12000000, 0), xy_crs=3857,
             radius=5000000, radius_crs=3857,
             fc=(.5, .5, 0, .4), ec="r", lw=3, n=100)

# GEODETIC CIRCLES with radius defined in meters
m.add_marker(xy=(-135, 35), radius=3000000, shape="geod_circles",
             fc="none", ec="r", hatch="///", lw=2, n=100)

# ----- MULTIPLE MARKERS
x = [-80, -40, 40, 80]    # x-coordinates of the markers
fc = ["r", "g", "b", "c"] # the colors of the markers

# N markers with the same radius
m.add_marker(xy=(x, [-60]*4), radius=10, fc=fc)

# N markers with different radius and properties
m.add_marker(xy=(x, [0]*4),  radius=[15, 10, 5, 2],
             fc=fc, ec=["none", "r", "g", "b"], alpha=[1, .5, 1, .5])

# N markers with different widths and heights
radius = ([15, 10, 5, 15], [5, 15, 15, 2])
m.add_marker(xy=(x, [60]*4), radius=radius, fc=fc)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've not heard of this library. It doesn't look like it natively supports ellipses; my concern is that I'm trying to validate some exported data, but the more code I have to write to validate it, the more likely the validation can no longer be trusted.